# How do I delete selected item from a combo box in the text file

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, text-files, removeclass

So the list in my combobox comes from a text file. The program allows the user to choose one item from the combobox. The selected item should be removed from the combobox and from the text file as well by clicking a button.

This code allows the program to get the items from the text file to my combobox:

```
string location = @"C:\\Users\\LMCPENA98\\Desktop\\COE114LPROJECT_MILLENNIUM_PAWS\\MillenniumPaws\\MillenniumPaws\\bin\\Debug\\Files.txt";
string[] temp = File.ReadAllLines(location);
int[] TagNumber = new int[temp.Length];
string[] Breed = new string[temp.Length];
string[] Name = new string[temp.Length];
decimal[] Price = new decimal[temp.Length];
//Getting all the values i the text file
for (int i = 0; i < TagNumber.Length; i++)
{
TagNumber[i] = int.Parse(temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("-")));
Breed[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("+"));
Breed[i] = Breed[i].Substring(Breed[i].LastIndexOf("-") + 1);
Name[i] = temp[i].Substring(0, temp[i].IndexOf("="));
Name[i] = Name[i].Substring(Name[i].LastIndexOf("+") + 1);
Price[i] = decimal.Parse(temp[i].Substring(temp[i].LastIndexOf("=") + 1));
}

Pound p;
for (int i = 0; i < Breed.Length; i++)
{
if (Breed[i] == cmbBx_breed.Text)
 {
  p = new Pound(TagNumber[i], Name[i], Price[i]);
  cmbBx_opts.Items.Add(p.GetEntry());
  }
 }
}
else
{
cmbBx_breed.Text = null;
}
```

This is how I'm letting the program know I'm done choosing an item:

```
private void btn_buy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new MessageBox_TYBuying().Show();
    cmbBx_opts.Items.Remove(cmbBx_opts.SelectedItem);
}
```

so when I started to program, the selected item in the combobox is now removed, but not on the text file. How do I do it??

Comment: Why not use a .json file or .xml file ? Far better and less complicated to use ..

Comment: My group and I don't know how to use those kinds of files yet

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "removing a line from a text file". All you can do is:

Approach 1)
Open the original file and either read all lines into a `List<string>`. Then, iterate over all these list entries and remove the one that needs to be removed. Then, write all the list entries back to the file.

Approach 2)
Rename the original file into some "backup" file. Open the backup file for reading and a new file with the original file name for writing. Read the backup file line by line. Write every line to the output file apart from the line you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

C++ Win32 Solution

```
char deleteCharArray[50];
int index = SendDlgItemMessageA(hDlg, ID_COMBOFILE, CB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
SendDlgItemMessageA(hDlg, ID_COMBOFILE, CB_GETLBTEXT, index, (LPARAM)deleteCharArray);
SendDlgItemMessageA(hDlg, ID_COMBOFILE, CB_DELETESTRING, index, 0);
    
vector<string> dataArray;
ifstream myFile("fileName.txt");
     
string line;
while (getline(myFile, line))
{
    dataArray.push_back(line);
}
     
string deleteThis = string(deleteCharArray);
     
for (auto it = dataArray.begin(); it != dataArray.end(); ++it)
{
    if (deleteThis == *it)
    {
        dataArray.erase(it);
        break;
    }
}
     
ofstream outFile("fileName.txt");
ostream_iterator<std::string> output_iterator(outFile, "\n");
copy(dataArray.begin(), dataArray.end(), output_iterator);
```